# Why is my WebSocket not working when I remove a form in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I am using WebSocket to display a certain value that counts how many seconds have passed on all visits to my site of all time. For example, if user A spends 20 seconds on my site, user B spends 30 seconds, and user C spends 10 seconds, 60 seconds are added to the counter. The counter is updated continuously. Here is my code in JavaScript and HTML. Now, I want to remove the form from the HTML, but when I do so, I get the text "[object HTMLTextAreaElement]." How can I solve this and get my site going?

```js
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');
function count() {
 if(! counter){
  var counter = 1;
 } else {
  counter = counter + 1;
 };
 socket.send(counter);
 document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = '<li>' + message + '</li>';
}
setInterval(count, 1000);
count();
window.close() = function() {
 socket.close();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        WebSockets Demo
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
      <h1>
        WebSockets Demo
      </h1>
      <ul id="messages">
      </ul>
      <form id="message-form" action="#" method="post">
        <textarea id="message" required></textarea>
        <button type="submit">
          Send Message
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your variable `message` is not defined in your code. Therefore, it will refer to your HTML DOM with corresponding id, which is `<textarea id="message" required></textarea>`.

I assume that you want to display returned message from echo server. If so, the code would be as follows:

```js
var socket = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');
var counter = 0;
function count() {
 counter++;
 socket.send(counter);
}
socket.onmessage = function(evt){
    document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML += '<li>' + evt.data + '</li>';
};
socket.onopen = function(){
    setInterval(count, 1000);
    count();
};
window.close() = function() {
 socket.close();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        WebSockets Demo
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
      <h1>
        WebSockets Demo
      </h1>
      <ul id="messages">
      </ul>
      <form id="message-form" action="#" method="post">
        <textarea id="message" required></textarea>
        <button type="submit">
          Send Message
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```